# Multiple Randomizer Plus Craving Levels

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, random

So I'm trying to develop a quick app for lunch that randomly selects a restaurant from an active array that gets values pushed into it from variables that get added on.  However because my co-workers don't believe in selecting restaurants by a toss of a coin, I figured it would be more interesting randomizing the restaurants 100 times, then allow Java to count how many of each instance each restaurant has been selected, then somehow count all those instances individually, finally adding the craving level from the variable's feeding the array to the final score.

So let's say I have two restaurants that are Chipotle and Panda Express.  Out of 100 toss ups Chipotle has been selected 47 times and Panda has been selected 53 times.  However because my craving level for Chipotle is 8 and Panda is 2, Chipotle will win because 47+8 defeats, 53+2. So far I wrote the randomize function and set the variables to feed the array however I'm not too sure how to do the rest. lol any help would be great!

```
var foodPlaces = [];
//Blank Array

//Restaurants Blelow//
foodPlaces.push({ //pushes to the end of the variable
    name: "Chipotle",
    type: "Mexican Food",
    url: "http://chipotle.com",
    craving: 8
})
foodPlaces.push({
    name: "Panda Express",
    type: "Chinese Food",
    url: "http://pandaexpress.com",
    craving: 2
})

//Function to pick food
var pickFood = function (){
    var randomFood = foodPlaces[Math.floor(Math.random()*foodPlaces.length)];
    alert(
        "Name: " + randomFood.name + 
        "\nType: " + randomFood.type + 
        "\nWebsite: " + randomFood.url); 
    if(randomFood.name === ""){
        pickFood();
    }
};
pickFood();
```

Comment: So perhaps code a loop that picks randomly 100 times keeping a total, then add in the craving factor? _"then allow Java"_ - I think you mean JavaScript. Why are you testing whether `randomFood.name` is an empty string? I don't think that could ever happen with the code shown.

Comment: Lol I'm new to JavaScript so just trying to learn the ropes. umm the reason why I'm testing the 'if(random.Food ==="")' is because if the string is blank or undefined (ill add this later) i just want the function to repeat so it repeats the function to select another food. seems to be working from the tests. How would you go about creating the loop if you dont mind me asking? Also would it be possible to record how many of each instance has been repeated that it can tally it up then count it against the craving level?

Comment: oh yea you're right. when i wrote the first version of the code, it didn't utilize the push function. that's why i originally kept that if statement. however yea with the new version since everything is just pushing into the array it's not needed.